# Start powershell job to run process that stays open in the background

Tags: powershell

Please note that while this post asks about coffeescript.cmd I don't think the answer has anything to do with it but more with me misunderstanding powershell's job system.

---

So to compile and watch coffeescript I can call

```
> coffee.cmd -cw ./scripts
```

which will start the coffeescript process. Due to the `w` watch flag, the process will stay open and recompile any changes until I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

What I would like is to start this process but have it run in the background so that I can continue using my console (yes, I know I can have multiple consoles). Ideally, any output from that job will just be pushed to my console as it happens.

So I thought I could do this

```
> start-job { coffee.cmd -cw .\scripts }
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
3      Job3            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             coffee.cmd -cw .\scripts
```

Unfortunately that seems a) swallow all output, and more importantly b) to finish immediately and not stay watching my directory

W:\surge\ogre> Get-Job

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
3      Job3            BackgroundJob   Completed     False           localhost             coffee.cmd -cw .\scripts
```

Note that I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185575/powershell-equivalent-of-bash-ampersand-for-forking-running-background-proce) but as I've demonstrated I can't seem to get the job to stay open even when I `Recieve-Job`.

What's going on? Are jobs not the right tool for this? What's the correct way to start a process that waits in the background? How do I redirect output from it to my console.

Comment: What version of Powershell?

Comment: @Eris 4.0 in my case. I think `Start-Job` was only introduced in 3, right?

Comment: Maybe it can't find coffee.cmd. If you do `Get-Job|Receive-Job` once you started the job, you receive nothing?

Comment: @MickyBalladelli `start-job { Get-Command coffee.cmd  } | receive-job -Wait` works

Comment: Powershell 3 introduced detached sessions, Powershell 2 would kill all background jobs when the parent session closed.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to figure out part of this thanks to a comment by @MickyBalladelli. Namely that this

```
start-job { Get-Location } | Receive-Job -Wait
```

returns ~/Documents. Aha! so relative paths won't work. When I do

```
Start-Job { coffee.cmd -cw w:\absoltue\path\to\scripts }
```

The job *does* remain running and will compile stuff in the background. Of course results (compliation successes and errors) don't get streamed to my console. In order to do that I need to explicitly call `Get-Job | Receive-Job`.

That's annoying but one step closer to what I *really* want.