# Can Start-Process start a process and let it run even when script ends in TFS?

Tags: windows, powershell, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm using `Start-Process` *cmdlet* as part of a Powershell script being executed by the new scriptable TFS build system.

My issue is that I'm starting some executables from my Powershell script and once the build step ends, it kills started processes.

I've also also tried to use `ProcessStartInfo` directly and `Start-Job` with no luck.

When I run that script alone it ends, but it leaves the started processes opened.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use start-Job:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { start C:\Windows\notepad.exe }
```

After exiting the PS, Notepad is still open

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185575/powershell-equivalent-of-bash-ampersand-for-forking-running-background-proce) for more info:

> if you start a script using Start-Process, it will survive the shell
>   termination, but if you started it from a console window then it stays
>   bound to that window and closing the window will terminate the process

Comment: Have you checked my updated question? I've already tried this too as part of the PS TFS build step with no luck... :\

Comment: Sry, didnt notice the change. Did you also tried start-process with -wait? Sure, this will hold your script, as long the other process runs ....

Comment: This doesn't work in my case. BTW tomorrow I'll try to run powershell using a command-line command TFS build step and see if this solves the issue...

Comment: Waiting isn't an option in my case because it's a build!! ;)