# Stop npm from cmd

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, cmd

I have started working on a reactJs project. After starting npm in command Prompt I'm unable to type anything. Should I close the cmd window or is there a way to stop npm.

```
You can now view ageteller in the browser.

Local:            http://localhost:3000/


On Your Network:  http://192.168.124.31:3000/

**Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.**
```

Ageteller is my project name and this is what my cmd is displaying with no type option.

Comment: Use CTRL + C to stop the running command

Comment: If you stop the Node server the app stops working (obviously). I suspect you're either after a [Powershell equivalent of bash ampersand (&) for forking/running background processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185575/powershell-equivalent-of-bash-ampersand-for-forking-running-background-proce) (I believe CMD never got that feature) or just want to open *two* windows.

Comment: What exactly did you type and enter at the Command Prompt, if you just entered `npm` as your question suggests, you may wish instead to try `Start npm`, `npm.cmd` or `Call npm.cmd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `CTRL+C`? If not, you should be fine to close the window. Not sure what you ran, but if you set it to run in the background, you can use `taskmgr` to force-kill the process.