# Windows 10: "The ampersand () character is not allowed"

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code

I am learning C language. I installed and configurated everything to start coding

But when I try to use ampersand (&) in scanf my program doesn't compile:

```
scanf("%f", &x);
```

I am getting this error:

> The ampersand () character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved
>   for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to
>   pass it as part of a string.

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to compile it as some other language instead of C?

Comment: What exactly are you using to compile your code?

Comment: Where do you enter your C code? This error message is from PowerShell, not from the compiler.

Comment: I am using vscode, configured with MinGW, my file extension is ".cpp" because I am using C++ compiler

Comment: PowerShell finally does support `&` to execute a process in the background... I cannot believe it took 6 versions to get to a lame emulation of a simple 40 year old feature in the unix shells. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892094/4593267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my bad, I had to change my file extension from .cpp to .c to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have everything installed and configured correctly.
The error looks like a PowerShell error, not a C compilation error.

Get a C compiler like MinGW-w64 GCC from http://winlibs.com/ and make sure to compile your C code (there is an example on that website showing you how to compile from the Command Prompt).

Comment: I am using MinGW on vscode it uses launch.json and tasks.json. I can compile any program that doesn't have an ampersand in it correctly.