# Why power-shell script execution stops when windows is idle

Tags: powershell

Why power-shell script execution stops when windows is idle.
Its so frustrating every time when i run a large scripts and go for a walk and when  comeback i see the scripts stopped .Once i log in then it starts to continue.

What is the solution for this so that my scripts never stops executing during this idle time

Comment: I don't know much about PowerShell, but try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185575/powershell-equivalent-of-bash-ampersand-for-forking-running-background-proce

Comment: They shouldn't. [Edit] the question and include a [mcve] that demonstrates stopping.

Comment: It's more likely a sleep/hibernation issue if anything but as vonPryz said, provide a MRE