# Running Private Ethereum blockchain node in background in windows

Tags: ethereum

I have a simple question but could not find answer to it. I know in linux nohup can be used to run geth node in background but how can i do it on windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell equivalent of bash ampersand (&) for forking/running background processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185575/powershell-equivalent-of-bash-ampersand-for-forking-running-background-proce)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have tried Start-Process method and some others given in that post but none worked. Geth node still shuts down when i close the window.